# Can't consume REST service from Android with HttpClient

Tags: android, google-app-engine, rest, httpclient

I'm implementing a RESTful service hosted in GAE trying to save Data to the Datastore.

```
@Path("/db")
public class DBAccess {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DBAccess.class.getName());

    // Allows to insert contextual objects into the class,
    // e.g. ServletContext, Request, Response, UriInfo
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void saveDataBase(final List<User> data,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse,
            @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {

        log.info("saveDatabae REST Service has been called.");

        Key dbKey = KeyFactory.createKey("DataBase", "default");

        Entity user;
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
                .getDatastoreService();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            user = new Entity("User", dbKey);
            user.setProperty("idUser", data.get(i).getIdUser());
            user.setProperty("idGMC", data.get(i).getIdGMC());

            datastore.put(user);
        }

        servletResponse.sendRedirect("../index.jsp");
    }
}
```

On the other hand I have an Android App trying to consume it like

```
private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
            throws IOException, JSONException {

        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();

        Log.v(TAG, "Posting params to " + endpoint);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endpoint);

        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        // Build JSON
        JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
            dato.put(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
        }

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
        String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

        Log.v(TAG, "HttpResponse is " + respStr);

    }
```

which is called by

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("regId", regId);
post("http://pickapp-server.appspot.com/rest/db", params);
```

In the GAE admin console I get the following log entry:

[image]

The point is, the User Entity is never created in the GAE Datastore. I guess the REST Service is not being called. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to see, but it looks like your service is generating a 400 response.  So your service is being called, but perhaps it's being blocked before it reaches your function.  Is there authentication in the way, or perhaps type validation which is failing?

Comment: None of that, no. But why am I not seeing my log though?

Comment: I speculate that there is something malformed about your request, which is being stopped by the JSON de-serialization (i.e. before it gets to your code in the function).  Can you call this REST API from another client?

Comment: That's right Steve, as @Peter_Knego stated below I was sending just one JSON instead of an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your REST method expects an array of JSON objects, while Android POST provides one JSON object. Try wrapping it in `JSONArray`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Peter_Knego, that was indeed one of the problems. For some reason I couldn't make it work with the JSONArray either so I  changed the saveDate method to receive just one User.